# Scope of where clause within let..in

Tags: haskell

```
encode :: String -> String
encode xs =
  let s = normalize xs
   in case s of
        [] -> []
        _ -> encode' s row col
        where row = isqrt (length s)
              col = length s `div` row
```

This gives the error "Variable not in scope: s". It seems the `where` clause within `let..in` can't see the variable `s` defined earlier.

How can I rewrite this?

Comment: Minor comment: in my own style I avoid mixing let and where in this way, even when it would work. The problem is that when one reads the code in the middle, finds a variable, and wonders how it is defined, one must check both _above_ the code (for the let) and _under_ the code (for the where). Personally, I find that a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `where` is defined at the function level, since `s` is not defined at that level, it thus can not access `s`. You can add extra declarations in the head of the `let … in …` level:

```
encode :: String -> String
encode xs =
  let s = normalize xs
      row = isqrt (length s)
      col = length s `div` row
   in case s of
        [] -> []
        _ -> encode' s row col
```

Or move everything to a `where` clause:

```
encode :: String -> String
encode xs = case s of
        [] -> []
        _ -> encode' s row col
  where s = normalize xs
        ns = length s
        row = isqrt ns
        col = ns `div` row
```

Comment: First option won't work because if `s` is empty, row=0 , and col will produce a divide by zero error. Second option won't work because the empty test needs to happen after normalizing the input.

Comment: Have you tried it? Haskell is lazy so `col` is not evaluated if the list is empty.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar: Haskell is lazy, hence it does not matter: it will only evaluate `row`, `col`, etc. if it needs these.

Comment: There's a third option: indent the `where` clause by one more character so that it attaches to the case clause instead of to the function. That seems closest to what @AbhijitSarkar intended.